# MySQL: select diverse statistics

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following setup:

```
-------------------------
| reference |   t_stamp |
-------------------------
|         1 | 2016-07-08|
|         1 | 2016-06-10|
|         1 | 2016-06-01|
|         2 | 2016-05-23|
-------------------------
```

I need to select unique `reference` rows with 1) the overall count by `reference` and 2) a separate count of last month from `t_stamp`.

The result should be:

```
------------------------------------
| reference | overall | last_month |
------------------------------------
|         1 |        3|          2 |
|         2 |        1|          0 |
------------------------------------
```

The first one is easy with 
`select reference, count(reference) overall from tbl1 group by reference`

How can I accomplish the second one in the same statement?

Thanks

Comment: Is this data set properly representative of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this kind of conditional count using `sum`:

```
sum(month(current_date - interval 1 month) = month(t_stamp))
```

Which can be `null`, in case there are no rows for the previous month. If you want to fetch `0` instead, you can use `coalesce(<...>, 0)`.

Comment: Nice one! Never knew it's possible to make a conditional sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With conditional counting using an `if()` function or `case` statement within a `sum()` or `count()`:

```
select reference,
       count(reference) overall,
       count(if(curdate() - interval 1 month>=t_stamp,1,null)) last_month
from tbl1 group by reference
```